# How to handle alerts running Chrome Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a problem with chrome running C# webdriver.

Whenever i click a link that spawns a popup the click command waits for 30sec or so and then fails with:

> http://localhost:48808/session/92d33d6032c3ac55cb8dc903adc2297b/element/:wdc:1318515744285/click

Is this a known issue in chrome?, the test runs without problems in IE and Firefox.

The link in question looks like this:

```
<a class="button" id="ContentPlaceHolderCMSEdit_CMSToolbar1_btnDelete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this page? It cannot be undone.');" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderCMSEdit$CMSToolbar1$btnDelete','')">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for alert handling via WebDriver was only implemented in either Chrome 15 or 16 (I can't remember exactly which). Neither version is yet available on the stable channel. You could try switching to the beta or dev channels and see if that works.